# A Problem with download a files from SFTP ? (exception Unhandled)

Tags: c#

I am trying to download the files or to make download automatically from SFTP into my local drive but i am getting this erro exception Unhandled : Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException: 'No such file'.
which i didn't understand it is  "Path to file on SFTP server"

```
string Host = "***";
int Port = ***;
string RemoteFileName = @"C:\Users\b.omran\Documents\SFTPFiles.gz";
string pathLocalFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "download_sftp_file.txt");
string Username = "**";
string Password = "****";

using (var sftp = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(pathLocalFile))
    {
        sftp.DownloadFile(RemoteFileName, fileStream);
    }

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Your _Remote_ FileName is `C:\Users\`? Most certainly it is not. You need to specify the path relative from the location you get when loggin in as said user.

Comment: @LocEngineer yes its not but how can i find the Remote ?!

Comment: Not sure if you really need the absolute path. Anyway, take a look here: https://www.componentpro.com/blog/details/absolute-path-remote-file-directory-sftp-server

Comment: Another thing: you want to download a gz archive and save it as a text file on your desktop?

Comment: what do you mean by gz archive ? could you explain more please

Comment: Your RemoteFileName has an extension of .gz. This is associated with a Linux/Unix format called gzip. Meaning it is a compressed file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip . It should be imperative to know what you download _before_ you download it...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an absolute path using client's property:

```
string relativePath = "testdir/test.dat";
string absolutePath = Path.Combine(sftp.WorkingDirectory, relativePath);
```

Comment: I can't find this method 'GetAbsolutePath' ?! is it in SftpClient class ?

Comment: It was previously about other SSH library for .NET . Already fixed (updated).